# Rinkeby test ethers not received

Tags: rinkeby

I tried to get Rinkeby test ethers from https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet. But even though the request is accepted, I am not receiving the ethers in my account. Can anyone suggest some alternative? Is the site down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

> http://thedapps.com/DAPP-Faucet/UI/

or

> https://faucet.ropsten.be/
>   this will give you only one ether.

Comment: Is there any website other than https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet to get Rinkeby test ethers? I am in-between of a project and I started with Rinkeby as test environment.

Comment: either you can use local network for deploying.use can use ganache over there you can have any amount of ether you want.but if you want to test it on ropsten then the option left for you is https://faucet.ropsten.be/ .but it will provide you just one ether per day. otherwise you have to mine the ether.and check if its the error of browser.for more reference read https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16600